# Hard Drive Stuck Read-Only

Tags: partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

So I am a new Linux user and honestly have very little idea what I'm even doing. After some finagling I finally got Ubuntu up and running with proper drivers and everything, but now I have a new issue. I'm using a 500 GB SSD for the OS and some other files, and have a 2 TB HDD installed as well. The issue is, the HDD is currently registering as Read-Only and telling me I'm not allowed to change the permissions as I am "not the owner" of it. This is a fresh install, so I honestly have no idea what to do here. I'm not dual-booting with Windows which seems to be the problem most people have with this, and can't really find any answers to my specific problem.

The output of `cat /etc/fstab` returns this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=3491f599-aad4-4052-8e2c-f30c97ababc2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=BA22-B420  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=54fb8d9f-09c7-41c0-abcf-ec392dd5cad8 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Also, the drive is currently blank.

I'm sure more information will be needed to actually answer my question, so please let me know what that is and how to get it. I appreciate any assistance that can be given. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1277997/edit) to clearly describe how you are *mounting* the HDD after boot. Also show us the complete output of `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Is there anything on the HDD?  Does it have data?  Is it partitioned?  What file system(s) are being used? If there is nothing of value on the drive, have you tried just formatting it?

Comment: @Nmath

I updated the question with that info. I could just reformat it, but I cannot stress enough how little I know what I'm doing on Linux. Do you have a link to good instructions on how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: @user535733 I added the requested output

Comment: Edit your question to show us an example of how you are seeing the read-only and the permissions problems.

Comment: Use the "[Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks)" application.  It has documentation but the tool is fairly self explanatory. Give yourself more credit!  If you are unclear about something, just ask.